# Use PowerShell to check an xml file in the Git staging area

Tags: git, powershell

I'm using Git with an ASP.Net web site with passwords stored in the web.config file.  To keep those from getting committed, I set up configuration section encryption, so the `connectionStrings` section of the file is encrypted -- unless I decrypt it to fool around with it.

Then to prevent accidentally committing it un-encrypted, I wrote a little PowerShell script that my local pre-commit hook invokes:

```
# Verifies that web.config's connectionStrings is encrypted.

[xml]$config = get-content .\Code\SlicerWeb\web.config
if ($config.configuration.connectionStrings.EncryptedData) {
    exit 0
    }
else {
    Write-Output "connectionStrings section is not encrypted."
    exit 1
    }
```

And this works fine, and is probably good enough.  But now I realize that what I really should do is check the contents of the file in the index (staging area), rather than the current file on disk.

How can I do a `get-content` of a file as it exists in the index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the : prefix to access objects in the current index. So this should work

```
[xml]$config = git show :./Code/SlicerWeb/web.config
```

(Backslashes in the path does not work here)